# How to use jdbc in a background thread with a Swing gui

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jdbc, swingworker

Currently, my entire gui has to freeze while the database connection is established. So instead, I wanted to run the connection in a background thread/task, and then tell the user when the connection has been established.

Should I use a `SwingWorker` or a normal `Thread` or something else of the kind?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/

Comment: @BrianRoach oh so that's what it's called, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I use a `SwingWorker` or a normal `Thread` or something else of the kind?

`SwingWorker` would be the optimal way, since it ensures that updates to the GUI are performed on the Event Dispatch Thread.  Having said that, it is also possible to use a `Thread`, just so long as you ensure the GUI is updated on the EDT.